# Use FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK to bring existed task to front

Tags: android, android-activity, back-stack

The android document of `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` said :

**When using this flag, if a task is already running for the activity you are now starting, then a new activity will not be started; instead, the current task will simply be brought to the front of the screen with the state it was last in.**

I make an demo to implement this, There are two app: A and B. A contains activity A1, B contains activity B1, B2.

I follow the step :`Home Screen(Application A icon) --> A1 (FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK to start B1)--> B1 -->B2 --> Home Screen(Application B icon)-->`  , as my understanding, click the application B icon from launcher to launch the Activity B1 will use the `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`, right? So it should bring the task started before to front, but unfortunately the fact is an new activity B1 is started and the B task stack is like this : (Bottom)B1 B2 B1.

How can i let the existed task brought to front when i click the application B icon in the launcher

Answer (score 0):

A and B are two different apps, Right ?
That means both will execute as a separate process and behave as separate task.

so when you set FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK to A it will create a separate task for A and make it as a root activity or brought to front the already existing instance of A.

When B is started from launcher, according to android normal launcher behavior it will start as a separate task and B will have separate stack.

Comment: `A1 (FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)--> B1` means when start B1 from A1, i use FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK.